# How do you solve a Laravel error like this?

Tags: php, laravel

```
   InvalidArgumentException 

  Attribute [order] does not exist.

  at D:\laravel\Project-Latihan-Website-Freelancer-main\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\RouteRegistrar.php:107
    103▕      */
    104▕     public function attribute($key, $value)
    105▕     {
    106▕         if (! in_array($key, $this->allowedAttributes)) {
  ➜ 107▕             throw new InvalidArgumentException("Attribute [{$key}] does not exist.");
    108▕         }
    109▕
    110▕         if ($key === 'middleware') {
    111▕             foreach ($value as $index => $middleware) {

  1   D:\laravel\Project-Latihan-Website-Freelancer-main\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Router.php:1355
      Illuminate\Routing\RouteRegistrar::attribute("order", "request")

  2   D:\laravel\Project-Latihan-Website-Freelancer-main\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade.php:261
      Illuminate\Routing\Router::__call("order")
```

i can't use php artisant serve

can solve my laravel problem, so it can be run with "php artisan serve"

Comment: At a glance, you have a may have a route defined to a function that doesn't exist, or has a property that doesn't exist. It's hard to tell without any code

Answer (score 0):

check your routes files (api.php and web.php),

either you have some routes without any controller function mentioned(not Route::resource), in that case just add controller function like, `'MyController@myfunc'`

or you have some routes where HTTP verb is incorrectly put as `order` instead of GET/PUT... etc

if you see any route like this,
`Route::order(........`
those route are creating this issue, change them to `Route::get` or `Route::post` according to your requirement